# Inconsistencies in Transform Definition between tf2 and ROS?

Tags: ros, transform, tf2

According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433314/homogeneous-transformation-matrix-how-to-use-it) definition of a homogeneous transformation matrix (pictured below), a transform consists of a rotation from source to destination and the location of the source origin relative to the destination origin. So, for example, if I want to transform a point from frame A to frame B, where B is 2 meters ahead of A, my transformation matrix would have an x translation of -2 (using ROS coordinate conventions).

To add this transform to my transform tree I'd expect to have to publish a TFMessage, with parent A and child B with a translation of -2. However, when I do this and use `tf2_ros::Buffer::lookupTransform` with the target frame as B and the source frame as A my transform contains a +2 x-translation. Additionally, this relationship between A & B, with B being 2 meters ahead of A, is only visualized correctly in RVIZ if my published transform contains a +2 translation. This leads me to believe that the homogeneous transform matrix is being represented in tf2 as I expect, with the negative translation, but in ROS it is being represented in the opposite way.

What exactly is the difference in transformation representation between ROS and tf2? Do the standard built-in tools all interpret transformations in the same way?

[image: Definition of Homogeneous transformation matrix. Source : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433314/homogeneous-transformation-matrix-how-to-use-it]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We believe we've figured this out. Here's what we've learned:

## What is a Transform?

Consider the diagram below which shows two coordinate frames, source and destination, as well as a vector representing some hypothetical measurement.
To get the source frame to align to the destination frame we'd have rotate counterclockwise by 15 degrees.
We'll define positive rotation as clockwise, so the pose of the destination frame in the source frame is negative 15 degrees.
If our data vector is defined in the source frame and we want to transform it to the destination frame, we'd rotate it by a positive 15 degrees; the below diagram helps illustrate this transformation.
When we refer to a transform we're talking about transforming data, and when we refer to a pose we're talking about the relationship between two coordinate frames.
These concepts of transform vs. pose are diametrically opposed, in that the pose is the inverse of the transform.
In more concise terms, the transform from the source frame to the destination frame is the inverse of the pose of the destination frame in the source frame.

[image: Shows two coordinate frames which are rotated relative to each other and how a data vector appears in both frames.]

Now let's consider a more complicated example, as illustrated in the below figure, where the frames are not only rotated 15 degrees apart but also offset from each other.
In this case, the destination frame is some positive x and y distance away from the source frame, so the pose of the destination frame in the source frame would be negative 15 degrees with a positive translation.
When transforming our data vector though we're in-fact subtracting some x and y offset.

[image: Shows two coordinate frames which are rotated and translated relative to each other and how a data vector appears in both frames.]

Below is a helpful illustration of how the transform is encoded in a 4x4 homogeneous transform matrix ([source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433314/homogeneous-transformation-matrix-how-to-use-it)).
In particular, we use a subset of homogeneous transforms called isometric transforms, which consist only of a rotation and translation (technically an isometry can also be a reflection rather than a rotation, but our implementation only allows them to be rotations), disallowing operations such as scaling, shearing, and rotation, and also preserving colinearity.
More information on isometries can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry).
The C++ [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) library is very useful for working with transforms and data, and there's already a library for converting between Eigen and the `geometry_msgs/TransformStamped`, [eigen_conversions](https://wiki.ros.org/eigen_conversions)

[image: Shows how a homogeneous transform (in particular a 3D isometry) is represented by a 4x4 matrix.]

When we lookup a transform from a source frame to a destination frame, using the `lookupTransform` API of the tf2 library, we receive the transform needed to transform a point in our source frame to a point in our destination frame.
You might've noticed previously that looking up the transform from source to destination gives opposite relationship between the two frames compared to what was published to the transform tree.
This is because the published transform tree actually contains poses, not transforms!
The `lookupTransform` API then converts these poses into actual transforms by inverting them.

#### How to Transform Data

Below are examples of how to utilize 3D isometric transforms to modify data as well as poses:

##### Construct a transform.

###### Inputs

- $R_A^B$ ∴ 3x3 rotation matrix, specifying how to rotate data in frame A to frame B.
- $t_B^A$ ∴ 1x3 translation vector, specifying location of frame A origin relative to frame B origin.

###### Output

$T_A^B$ ∴ Transform from frame A to frame B.

###### Expression

$T_A^B = \begin{bmatrix} R_A^B & t_B^A \\\ \left<0,0,0\right> & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

##### Construct a pose.

###### Inputs

- $R_A^B$ ∴ 3x3 rotation matrix, specifying orientation of frame A relative to frame B.
- $t_B^A$ ∴ 1x3 position vector, specifying location of frame A origin relative to frame B origin.

###### Output

$P_A^B$ ∴ Pose of frame A in frame B.

###### Expression

$P_A^B = \begin{bmatrix} R_A^B & t_B^A \\\ \left<0,0,0\right> & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

##### Rotate a 3D vector in frame A to frame B.

###### Inputs

- $R_A^B$ ∴ 3x3 rotation matrix, specifying how to rotate data in frame A to frame B.
- $\vec{v}_A = \left<{v_x, v_y, v_z}\right>_A$ ∴ 3D vector in frame A.

###### Output

$\vec{v}_B = \left<{v_x, v_y, v_z}\right>_B$ ∴ 3D vector in frame B.

###### Expression

$\vec{v}_B = R_A^B * \vec{v}_A$

##### Transform a point in frame A to frame B.

###### Inputs

- $T_A^B$ ∴ Transform from frame A to frame B.
- $\vec{p}_A = \left<{p_x, p_y, p_z, 0}\right>_A$ ∴ 3D vector in frame A. Zero is added as 4th element so we can multiply by the transformation matrix.

###### Output

$\vec{p}_B = \left<{p_x, p_y, p_z, 0}\right>_B$ ∴ 3D vector in frame B.

###### Expression

$\vec{p}_B = T_A^B * \vec{p}_A$

##### Composing multiple transforms into a single transform.

###### Inputs

- $T_A^B$ ∴ Transform from frame A to frame B.
- $T_B^C$ ∴ Transform from frame B to frame C.

###### Output

$T_A^C$ ∴ Transform from frame A to frame C.

###### Expression

$T_A^C = T_B^C * T_A^B$

##### Composing multiple poses into a single pose.

###### Inputs

- $P_B^A$ ∴ Pose of frame B in frame A.
- $P_C^B$ ∴ Pose of frame C in frame B.

###### Output

- $P_C^A$ ∴ Pose of frame C in frame A.

###### Expression

$P_C^A = P_B^A * P_C^B$

##### Inverting an Isometry

###### Input

$I = \begin{bmatrix} R & t \\\ \left<0,0,0\right> & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ ∴ Isometric transform or pose to invert.

###### Output

$I^{-1}$ ∴ Inverted isometric transform or pose.

###### Expression

$I^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} R^{-1} & t^{-1} \\\ \left<0,0,0\right> & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, where

- $R^{-1} = transpose(R)$
- $t^{-1} = -R^{-1} * t$

##### Identities

- $T_A^B = P_A^B = inverse(T_B^A) = inverse(P_A^B)$
- $T_B^A = P_B^A = inverse(T_A^B) = inverse(P_B^A)$